What version of RabbitMQ is recommended for compatibility with Spring Boot 3.2.3 and Spring AMQP 3.1.2?
I'm using Spring Boot 3.2.3 and Spring AMQP 3.1.2, and I'm trying to find out which version of RabbitMQ is recommended for compatibility. However, I couldn't find any information on the RabbitMQ official website or in blog posts. Could you please provide some technical insight into which versions are compatible, or if using the latest version would be sufficient?

https://www.rabbitmq.com/release-information
https://spring.io/projects/spring-amqp#overview

I haven't tested anything yet; I'm still in the process of researching before conducting any tests.

This is more question about RabbitMQ Java Client and RabbitMQ broker compatibility since Spring AMQP is fully based on com.rabbitmq:amqp-client.
But since I don't see anything like that in their documentation, I can assume that this Java client works with any supported RabbitMQ broker versions.
